# A pilot's messages

Tags: lateral-thinking, knowledge, steganography, geography

A friend of mine works as a pilot, so he travels a lot and I don't see him that often. But every year around the same time he sends me a message. He has been doing that ever since 1997.
Here is a list of all the messages he sent:

> **1997:** 0.6 - LAFRBRAV - Kg
>   **1998:** 1.8 - BVOHOTXY - Is
>   **1999:** 5.8 - JULITTROMOIRRA - wdn
>   **2000:** 2.6 - LFOOOVB - Dk
>   **2001:** 2.4 - CHRLPPHL - sn
>   **2002:** 5.0 - NGOMM - v
>   **2003:** 4.8 - OMOINDIAXA - Tuk
>   **2004:** 3.0 - DSTGO - Uk
>   **2005:** 4.2 - INDIAHOVITO - G
>   **2006:** 4.0 - TGOHOTE - id
>   **2007:** 2.4 - HOTLCHOLM - Srb
>   **2008:** 4.8 - BVOECHOGOLF - ussi
>   **2009:** 3.2 - DELTMIKEECH - Nrwy
>   **2010:** 5.8 - OSCSILI - Gny
>   **2011:** 2.8 - DLTUFOMS - zbj
>   **2012:** 5.2 - GOLFYAKLTA - Sw
>   **2013:** 3.6 - IIXY - Dn
>   **2014:** 2.0 - CHLEPPHOEL - us
>   **2015:** 4.6 - VICTORIIACHO - Sw
>   **2016:** ???

Unfortunately I lost last year's message. Can you help me figure out what it was?

**Note:** a good starting point for this is to try and make sense out of the other messages.

Comment: I spy Serbia, Russia, and Norway in there ...

Comment: Numbers make me think of earthquakes...

Comment: I thought pilots didn't use "DELTA"

Comment: Can I just say, this is a *fantastic* puzzle. Even though I haven't finished solving it yet, I love the multi-layeredness of it, the way different clues cue and confirm each other, and I think you've pitched the difficulty just right.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean about one informing the next

Comment: Shouldn't this have the [tag:geography] tag?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Yup, I guess you could add that one. I'm not very familiar with all the possible tags yet, so I just put up a few that I thought were the most useful.

Comment: Wouldn't a _pilot_ tend to work in terms of 4-letter ICAO codes rather than 3-letter IATA codes?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Two things jumped out at me as soon as I saw this puzzle.

- Firstly, the mixed-case letter strings on the far right. Several of them look like

  > country names with certain letters removed. For instance, **Srb** -> Serbia, **ussi** -> Russia, and **Nrwy** -> Norway.
- Secondly, the all-caps letter strings in the middle. Several of them start with what look like

  > words from the [<strike>NATO</strike> IACO phonetic alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_phonetic_alphabet). Reading down, we can immediately spot JULI(E)T, INDIA, HOT(E)L, DELT(A), GOLF, VICTOR.

Looking at it a little more closely, I noticed that

> the letters missing from the country names seem to be identical in each line to the letters removed from the <strike>NATO</strike> IACO phonetic alphabet words.

So let's fill in some of those letters and see where we get:

> 1997: 0.6 - **DE**L**T**A / **UNI**F**O**R**M** / BRAV**O** - **United** K**in**g**dom**
>  1998: 1.8 - B**RA**VO / HOT**EL** / X**RA**Y - Is**rael**
>  1999: 5.8 - JULI**E**TT / ROM**E**O / **S**I**E**RRA - **S**w**e**d**e**n
>  2000: 2.6 - **A**LF**A** / **R**O**ME**O / **N**OV**EM**B**ER** - D**enmar**k
>  2001: 2.4 - CH**A**RL**IE** / P**A**P**A** / H**OTE**L - **E**s**to**n**ia**
>  2002: 5.0 - **TA**NGO / **LI**M**A** / **LI**M**A** - **Lat**v**ia**
>  2003: 4.8 - **R**OM**E**O / INDIA / X**R**A**Y** - Tu**r**k**ey**
>  2004: 3.0 - **IN**D**IA** / S**IERRA** / T**AN**GO - Uk**raine**
>  2005: 4.2 - INDIA / **EC**HO / VI**C**TO**R** - G**reece**
>  2006: 4.0 - **ALFA** / T**AN**GO / HOTE**L** - **F**i**nlan**d
>  2007: 2.4 - HOT**E**L / **E**CHO / L**I**M**A** - S**e**rb**ia**
>  2008: 4.8 - B**RA**VO / ECHO / GOLF - **R**ussi**a**
>  2009: 3.2 - DELT**A** / MIKE / ECH**O** - N**o**rw**a**y
>  2010: 5.8 - OSC**AR** / SI**ERRA** / LI**MA** - G**erma**ny
>  2011: 2.8 - D**E**LT**A** / U**NI**FO**R**M / S**IERRA** - **A**z**er**b**ai**j**an**
>  2012: 5.2 - GOLF / YA**N**K**E** / **DE**LTA - Sw**eden**
>  2013: 3.6 - **M**I**KE** / **M**I**KE** / X**RA**Y - D**e**n**mark**
>  2014: 2.0 - CH**AR**L**I**E/P**A**P**A**/HO**T**EL - **A**us**tria**
>  2015: 4.6 - VICTOR / I**ND**IA / **E**CHO - Sw**eden**

On each line, the all-caps part deciphers to

> three letters, which together with the context of the message suggests **airport codes**.

Furthermore,

> the airport given by this three-letter code is in the country given by the right-most part of the *previous* line! For instance, in 2008, BEG is Nikola Tesla Airport in Belgrade, **Serbia** - the country mentioned in 2007.

Having noticed this connection, I actually used it quite a lot to help me find some of the missing letters to reconstruct the above.

So now we have the following list of airports:

> [Dublin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dublin_Airport) (DUB), Ireland
>  [Birmingham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birmingham_Airport) (BHX), United Kingdom
>  [Atarot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atarot_Airport) (JRS), Israel (Palestine?)
>  [Stockholm Arlanda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stockholm_Arlanda_Airport) (ARN), Sweden
>  [Copenhagen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copenhagen_Airport) (CPH), Denmark
>  [Tallinn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tallinn_Airport) (TLL), Estonia
>  [Riga International](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riga_International_Airport) (RIX), Latvia
>  [Istanbul Ataturk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Istanbul_Atat%C3%BCrk_Airport) (IST), Turkey
>  [Kiev International](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kyiv_International_Airport_(Zhuliany)) (IEV), Ukraine
>  [Athens International](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athens_International_Airport) (ATH), Greece
>  [Helsinki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helsinki_Airport) (HEL), Finland
>  [Belgrade Nikola Tesla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belgrade_Nikola_Tesla_Airport) (BEG), Serbia
>  [Domodedovo International](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domodedovo_International_Airport) (DME), Russia
>  [Oslo Gardermoen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oslo_Airport,_Gardermoen) (OSL), Norway
>  [Dusseldorf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%BCsseldorf_Airport) (DUS), Germany
>  [Heydar Aliyev International](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heydar_Aliyev_International_Airport) (GYD), Azerbaijan
>  [Malmo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malm%C3%B6_Airport) (MMX), Sweden
>  [Copenhagen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copenhagen_Airport) (CPH), Denmark
>  [Vienna International](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vienna_International_Airport) (VIE), Austria

Thanks to [Sconibulus](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/46412/5373), these correspond to

> the locations of the [Eurovision Song Contests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Eurovision_Song_Contest_winners#List) in the respective years. (This explains why the airport in one line matches the country in the *previous* line - because each year's winner becomes the next year's host.)

Looking at the linked table, we can now spot that the number on the far left of each line in the puzzle corresponds to

> the date of the ESC (you did mention that the messages come "every year around the same time"). E.g. for 2010, the number 5.8 equals 29/5 and the ESC was on the 29th of May.

---

So **in the row for each year, we have**

> **the date, location, and winner of that year's Eurovision Song Contest** (the date encoded by simply treating the slash as division; the location encoded by an airport IATA code in the IACO phonetic alphabet, and the location and winner encoded by removing their common letters).

And **the final answer is**

> **2016: 2.8 - LFOMOOVMB - Uki**, because the 2016 ESC was held on 14/5 in Stockholm and won by Ukraine, giving "ALFA/ROMEO/NOVEMBER - Ukraine", from which we remove the letters R, A, N, and E (thanks to [Henning Makholm](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46410/a-pilots-messages/46411?noredirect=1#comment140768_46411) for realising that the letters removed are precisely the ones found in both strings).

Comment: The pattern in the removals seems to be simply that every letter that appears in _both_ parts will be omitted. So N in your solution should go too.

Comment: @Henning Dang. Not sure how I missed that. Thanks and edited!

Comment: That's it exactly, great job!

Comment: I would rather say that the phonetic alphabet used is the ICAO Phonetic alphabet. Not different from the NATO one, but more fitting considering the guy is a pilot.

Comment: @SMS Good point - edited :-)

Comment: You talk only about the host (of the Eurovision song contest) when trying to find the pattern, but then in your final answer you use the *winner* instead of the host. Shouldn't the final answer be constructed using *Sweden* instead of *Ukraine*?

Comment: @Jasper The winner and the host in each year are *both* involved. (The reason why the country at the end of one line matches the airport in the middle of the next is just because each year's ESC winner becomes the host country the next year.)

Comment: @randal'thor I missed the *of the previous line* part of your explanation. The part that a winner is the next year's host is something you are using but not actually mentioning in the answer (I knew it was true, but I think mentioning it would have pointed me at the part of your explanation I was missing)

Comment: @Jasper Fair point; edited. (The reason I didn't mention it originally was because I'd worked out all the airports and countries long before I - or rather Sconibulus - found the ESC connection.)

Answer (score 15):

Working from @Rand al'Thor's excellent answer, we have determined

> These are encoded messages with missing letters, the same letters from both left and right.
> The words on the left are NATO Phonetic Airport codes, and the words on the right are countries.
> The Airport codes match the countries from the prior year.

From this, we were able to determine that the 2016 message should have a left character part of

> An airport in Sweden.

I was able to notice that

> The cities and countries in the message correspond with the Eurovision contest, and so the airport code needs to be specifically from Stockholm, and the country on the right is to be Ukraine.

A potential 2016 message could have been

> **2016**: ?.? - BVOMLF - Un

From

> bRAvomIKEAlfA - uKRAInE

And we still haven't deciphered the meaning of the numbers.

Comment: "SMP" appears to refer to "Stockholm Airport" in Papua New Guinea.

Comment: @AdamV oops, that's a good point, give me a moment and I'll fix it

Comment: "BMA" airport would be "BVOMLF" (no K). Other possible airports in Sweden could be GOT (which would be "GOLFOSCTGO - Ukie") or NYO (which would be "OVMBYOSC - Ui").

Answer (score 7):

#### Partial answer

As rand al'thor, I figured out the names of

> the countries and the airports.

The system seems to be:

> For each year, the airport is of the city where the [Eurovision Song Contest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurovision_Song_Contest) was held that year. The country is the winner of that contest.

For example:

> **2009**: 3.2 - DELTMIKEECH - Nrwy:
> Delta, mike, echo (DME - Domodedovo, in Moscow, Russia). Winner was Norway.

We notice:

> The letters that are left out in the airport code and the country name are the letters that occur in both. So, in the above example, A and O occur in both DELTAMIKEECHO and NORWAY, so they are removed.

I have not yet figured out the significance of the numbers, but can make a partial guess for 2016:

> **2016**: ??? - LFOMOOVMB - Uki. (ALFAROMEONOVEMBER - Ukraine).

Comment: Oh, I see Sconibulus came to the same conclusion some time ago... had not refreshed the page.